# Is the expression "in seek of" acceptable?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, formality

Is this sentence correct, or are there better ways to express it:

> **In seek of** an ideal start for my career, I am applying for the PhD program at your school.

Am I using the wrong verb here, should I use instead, [**in search of**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in-search-of?s=t) ?
What formulaic expressions or phrases could I use in place of *in seek of*?

I am looking for something formal, but also native-like.

Comment: You might be looking for this expression [*It's important to get off on the right foot in this new job.*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/on-the-right-foot--get-off)  So, you could write: “In order for my career to start off on the right foot, I am applying...”

Comment: If you dislike or feel uncomfortable with my edit you can rollback to the previous version, but if you do show some minimal research, users will be more inclined to answer. Good luck!

Comment: Please do not edit the question to remove it altogether. If you are not happy with how the question is presented, feel free to improve it; but removing the essential parts of it completely just invalidates the answers you’ve received and makes it a non-question.

Answer (score 3):

"In seek of" is not a common expression.

You could either say:

> In *search* of an ideal start for my career, ...

This uses the verb *search* and is a common expression.

or you can use

> *Seeking* an ideal start for my career, ...

This uses the verb *seek* as a gerund. Seek doesn't sound right with an indirect object, which is why *in seek of* sounds wrong to me, I think.

Also, you wouldn't use "*searching* an ideal start ... " but you could use

> *Searching for* an ideal start for my career, ...

*Seek* sounds a little more formal to me than *search*, but it's probably personal preference. None of these choices is informal or slang; they will all suit for an application letter.

Answer (score 1):

*I am applying for the PhD program at your school, as I consider it the ideal qualification for my proposed career in rocket science.*